# Rename project, Then what?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, rename

I renamed my Xcode project, now it is saying that I will lose changes if I close; I cant't figure out how to save the renamed Xcode project!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you rename the project from Finder? Then just select "Close and Lose Changes", then re-open the project.

Comment: @Felizyz, No I went: Project > Rename...; and renamed it from within Xcode.

Comment: nvm, I restored to a Snapshot and then renamed from Finder. Thanks.